# Testing FB Pixel locally

Tags: facebook, localhost, local, mamp, pixel

Is it possible to test the Pixel on MAMP without uploading to Live?

I've had to jump on a live site that someone else built and I'd like to test whether the ATC button is firing the AddToCart event instead of Purchase as it's currently configured. Is this possible? I can't find anything about working locally.

Cheers

Edit: I'd better clarify further—the Pixel works, but only PageView is working, when on Live there's also 'Microdata Automatically Detected', and the ATC button fires 'Puchase' and 'Button Click Automatically Detected' which I can't replicate locally, even though I've pulled everything down.

Comment: Not sure if any of that functionality requires Facebook to make any requests to the page in question, that of course would not work when you are “local”. Maybe try and set up an ngrok tunnel to make everything publicly available, and test again.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help. No idea what an ngrok tunnel is though, I'll take a look.

Comment: https://ngrok.com/ allows you to easily set up an HTTPS tunnel, so that your dev server can be accessed from the outside.